# Opening files from directory in specific order

Tags: python, directory, python-imaging-library

I have a folder that contains around 500 images that I am rotating at a random angle from 0 to 360. The files are named `00i.jpeg` where `i = 0` then `i = 1`. For example I have an image named `009.jpeg` and one named `0052.jpeg` and another one `00333.jpeg`. My code below works as is does rotate the image, but how the files are being read through is not stepping correctly.

I would think I would need some sort of stepping code chunk that starts at 0 and adds one each time, but I'm not sure where I would put that. `os.listdir` doesn't allow me to do that because (from my understanding) it just lists the files out. I tried using `os.walk` but I cannot use `cv2.imread`. I receive a `SystemError: <built-in function imread> returned NULL without setting an error` error.

Any suggestions?

```
import cv2
import imutils
from random import randrange
import os

os.chdir("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\training\\JPEG")


j = 0
for infile in os.listdir("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\training\\JPEG"):
    filename = 'testing' + str(j) + '.jpeg'
    i = randrange(360)
    image = cv2.imread(infile)
    rotation_output = imutils.rotate_bound(image, angle=i)
    os.chdir("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\rotate_test")
    cv2.imwrite("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\rotate_test\\" + filename, rotation_output)
    os.chdir("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\training\\JPEG")
    j = j + 1
```

```
print(infile)
000.jpeg
001.jpeg
0010.jpeg
00100.jpeg
...
```

Needs to be:

```
print(infile)
000.jpeg
001.jpeg
002.jpeg
003.jpeg
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a list of files first, then use sort with `key` where the key is an integer version of the file name without extension.

```
files = os.listdir("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\training\\JPEG")
files.sort(key=lambda x:int(x.split('.')[0]))

for infile in files:
    ...
```

Practical example:

```
files = ['003.jpeg','000.jpeg','001.jpeg','0010.jpeg','00100.jpeg','002.jpeg']
files.sort(key=lambda x:int(x.split('.')[0]))
print(files)
```

Output

```
['000.jpeg', '001.jpeg', '002.jpeg', '003.jpeg', '0010.jpeg', '00100.jpeg']
```